# How to remove numbers from string using Regex.Replace?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to use `Regex.Replace` to remove all numbers and signs from a string.

Example input: `123- abcd33`
Example output: `abcd`

Comment: you also want the "- " removed?  Those are not numbers...

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
```

The `\d` identifier simply matches any digit character.

Comment: What is the purpose of the dash? I know it's used for ranges, but there's nothing at the right?

Comment: Purpose is to remove it together with numbers. See input/output example in question.

Answer (score 28):

You can do it with a LINQ like solution instead of a regular expression:

```
string input = "123- abcd33";
string chars = new String(input.Where(c => c != '-' && (c < '0' || c > '9')).ToArray());
```

A quick performance test shows that this is about five times faster than using a regular expression.

Comment: @SirDemon: Yes, LINQ is usually not the fastest option, but regular expressions have a bigger initial overhead. For operations on short strings setting up the RegEx object takes longer than the actual work.

Comment: @Guffa Do you know how this scales? Lets say on 50k records should I go for RegEx?

Comment: @ArnoldWiersma: Either should scale pretty well, they are both basically linear, so there are no nasty surprises. I can't tell off hand which would be faster, you would have to test that.

Comment: alternatively `new string(text.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());`

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek, the problem here is that this also trims the string

Answer (score 13):

Blow codes could help you...

Fetch Numbers:

```
return string.Concat(input.Where(char.IsNumber));
```

Fetch Letters:

```
return string.Concat(input.Where(char.IsLetter));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = Regex.Replace("123- abcd33", @"[0-9\-]", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

Different methods and which is the fastest if you have 100000 iterations to do.

Code:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        var maxIterations = 100000;

        Console.WriteLine(@"Removing digits from string: ""1mir1112211a3bc9"" with Total {0}x iterations ",maxIterations);
        Console.WriteLine("\nReplace Operations");
        sw.Start();
        var str = "1mir1112211a3bc9";
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxIterations; i++)
        {
            str = "1mir1112211a3bc9";

            str = str.Replace("1", "")
                     .Replace("2", "")
                     .Replace("3", "")
                     .Replace("4", "")
                     .Replace("5", "")
                     .Replace("6", "")
                     .Replace("7", "")
                     .Replace("8", "")
                     .Replace("9", "")
                     .Replace("0", "");
        }
        sw.Stop();
        
        Console.WriteLine("Finalstring: " + str);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");

        sw.Reset();

        //list for and if 
        Console.WriteLine("\nList Operations:");
        sw.Start();
        var str2 = "1mir1112211a3bc9";
        var listOfchars = new List<char>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxIterations; i++)
        {
             str2 = "1mir1112211a3bc9";
            for (int j = 0; j < str2.Length; j++)
            {
                if( !(char.IsDigit(str2[j])))
                    listOfchars.Add(str2[j]);
            }
            str2 = new string(listOfchars.ToArray());
            listOfchars.Clear();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Finalstring: " + str2);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");

           sw.Reset();
        //LINQ
        Console.WriteLine("\nLINQ Operations");

        sw.Start();
            var str1 = "1mir1112211a3bc9";
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxIterations; i++)
        {
            str1 = "1mir1112211a3bc9";
            str1 = String.Concat(str1.Where(c => c != '-' && (c < '0' || c > '9')) );
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Finalstring: " + str1);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");

        //Regex
        sw.Reset();
        
        Console.WriteLine("\nRegex Operations");

        sw.Start();
        var str3 = "1mir1112211a3bc9";
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxIterations; i++)
        {
            str3 = "1mir1112211a3bc9";
            str3 = Regex.Replace(str3, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Finalstring: " + str3);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");
```

Here are the Results:

Removing digits from string: "1mir1112211a3bc9" with Total **100000x iterations**

Replace Operations 
Finalstring: mirabc
Elapsed time: 37,8307 Milliseconds

List Operations:
Finalstring: mirabc
Elapsed time: **16,7803 Milliseconds**

LINQ Operations
Finalstring: mirabc
Elapsed time: 34,5803 Milliseconds

Regex Operations
Finalstring: mirabc
Elapsed time: 252,1907 Milliseconds

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I liked seeing the comparison between the methods. I will still use the Regex approach for readability and because I only have a few iterations to do, but it is still good to know how much slower the Regex is compared to the other methods.

Answer (score 3):

As a string extension:

```
    public static string RemoveIntegers(this string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
    }
```

Usage:

```
"My text 1232".RemoveIntegers(); // RETURNS "My text "
```

Answer (score 2):

the best design is:

```
public static string RemoveIntegers(this string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
text= re.sub('[0-9\n]',' ',text)
```

install regex in python which is re then do the following code.