# Finding all numbers in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, numbers, find

Part of my app has an area where users enter text into a textBox control. They will be entering both text AND numbers into the textBox. When the user pushes a button, the textBox outputs its text into a string, finds all numbers in the string, multiplies them by 1.14, and spits out the typed text into a pretty little textBlock.

Basically, what I want to do is **find all the numbers in a string**, multiply them by 1.14, and insert them back into the string.

At first, I thought this may be an easy question: just [Bing the title](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=Finding+all+numbers+in+a+string+c%23&first=1&FORM=PERE) and see what comes up.

But after two pages of now-purple links, I'm starting to think I can't solve this question with my own, very skimpy knowledge of Regex.

However, I did find a hearty collection of helpful links:

- [This article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-numbers) from DotNetPerls
- [This code snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/15623/get-number-from-string/) at Snipplr
- [This question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/csharplanguage/thread/1EF79BE7-091B-4455-80CC-4DC2CACDDFA1) on MSDN
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657282/how-to-remove-numbers-from-string-in-regex-replace/1657288#1657288) on StackOverflow
- [This article](http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/1167258/how_to_extract_numbers_from_a_string.html?cat=59) from AssociatedContent
- [This question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/84990ad2-5046-472b-b103-f862bfcd5dbc/) on MSDN
- [This article](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Language-Basics/Fasterwaytogetnumberfromstring.htm) on Java2s.com

**Please note:** A few of these articles come close to doing what I want to do, by fetching the numbers from the strings, but none of them **find all the numbers in the string**.

**Example:**
A user enters the following string into the textBox: "Chicken, ice cream, 567, cheese! Also, 140 and 1337."

The program would then spit out this into the textBlock: "Chicken, ice cream, 646.38, cheese! Also, 159.6 and 1524.18."

Comment: Numbers... or **digits**?  There's a _huge_ difference.

Comment: Numbers, excluding numbers written as 'one' and 'two' but not numbers written as '1' and '2'.

Comment: What about `-.040`?  Or `1/3`? Or `0x8f`? Or `2^8`? Or `1e7`?  Those are all numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that matches the numbers, and use the `Regex.Replace` method. I'm not sure what you include in the term "numbers", but this will replace all non-negative integers, like for example `42` and `123456`:

```
str = Regex.Replace(
  str,
  @"\d+",
  m => (Double.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value) * 1.14).ToString()
);
```

If you need some other definition of "numbers", for example scientific notation, you need a more elaboarete regular expression, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Wow! Seems to work wonderfully... but you were missing an ampersand until my edit 1 second in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Freely adopted from the sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx)

Beware of your regional options (since you're parsing and serializing floating point numbers)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MyClass
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var input = "a 1.4 b 10";

      Regex r = new Regex(@"[+-]?\d[\d\.]*"); // can be improved

      Console.WriteLine(input);
      Console.WriteLine(r.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceCC)));
   }

   public static string ReplaceCC(Match m)
   {
       return (Double.Parse(m.Value) * 1.14).ToString();
   }
}

[mono] ~ @ mono ./t.exe
a 1.4 b 10
a 1.596 b 11.4
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to this over Guffa's answer?

Comment: The regex is slightly more involved (but not perfect). Otherwise, no (_aside from providing more documentation links and being slightly more verbose for clarity, actually compiling and runnign - hehe :)_)