# How can i get only a part of a file name?

Tags: c#

For example i have this function that search for files:

```
public void Search(string strExtension,
                            DirectoryInfo di,
                            List<FileSystemInfo> pResult)
        {
            try
            {

                foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label2.Text = fi.Name));
                    }
                    if (fi.Name == "MessageLog.xsl")
                    {
                        foreach (FileInfo fii in di.GetFiles())
                        {
                        if (fii.Extension == strExtension)
                            pResult.Add(fii);
                        }
                        if (InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label4.Text = pResult.Count.ToString() + Environment.NewLine));
                        }

                    }
                }

                    foreach (DirectoryInfo diChild in di.GetDirectories())
                        Search(strExtension, diChild, pResult);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

When the search is over im using this small class :

```
public class MyItem
        {
            public FileSystemInfo fsi { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return this.fsi.Name;
            }
        }
```

And show in the backGroundWorker completed event the files names:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < this.fsi.Count; i++)
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(new MyItem() { fsi = fsi[i] });
            }


        }
```

The result in the listBox is for example like this:

```
danny125645.xml

yaron576567.xml
```

This are file names without the directories.

Is there anyway to parse the file name so it will be without the numbers ? For example:

```
danny.xml

yaron.xml
```

Comment: [How to remove numbers from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657282/how-to-remove-numbers-from-string-in-regex-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your class and change:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Regex.Replace(this.fsi.Name, @"[\d]", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: aahh take out the `-` from the regex. Don't make it so obvious you're copy+pasting.

Comment: See my comment to the question above.

Comment: Oh I see it now - heh, I just copied it from some source I already had laying out. Coincidence!

Comment: Zaid you link above also contain - in the solution there.

Comment: And its working but both your link and Burhan solution are the same idea.

Comment: @DanielLip yes the `-` needs to be taken out, which is what I asked Burhan to do. Unless you also want to remove "-" characters.

Comment: Zaid but i didnt take out the - and its working i mean in your link !

Comment: @DanielLip it will work but the regex will remove "-" characters as well, which you may not want.

Comment: Zaid look at the link you gave me the solution there including the - and its working for me. So why you need to remove it ?

Comment: @DanielLip - this solution removes both numbers and dashes.  If that's what you want, then leave the dash in.  Otherwise, remove it. It only works because you don't have dashes in your file names.

Comment: Zaid ah now i understand. But in my case the files names are without any - so its not a matter but i will remove it.

Comment: OK i understand now . Sorry for the mess.