# Mapping list of items to shortest starting string in list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of 5 arbitrary user-inputted strings:

```
List<string> original = new List<string>() {"a", "a1", "a2", "b", "b1"} ;
```

For each string in the original collection, I want to get back the shortest string in the list which starts the current string:

> `"a"  -> "a"`
>   `"a1" -> "a"`
>   `"a2" -> "a"`
>   `"b"  -> "b"`
>   `"b1" -> "b"`

**How can I do this using LINQ?**

Some more examples:

```
{a, ghjkjajj,hkj,bn,n} => {a, ghjkjajj,hkj,bn,n}
{ghj465,abn,abn1,hj,ui} => {ghj465,abn,abn,hj,ui}
{gh465,gh1,gh} => {gh,gh,gh}
{abcd,ab} => {ab,ab}
```

Comment: so... it's just a matter of truncating the number from the name?

Comment: Yes , but if the sequence is {a,a1,c34,b,b1} I need {a,a,c34,b,b}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1657293/1982631

Comment: @Manoz: I need it to be generic ,  the input is not static , sometimes it can be {c34} othertime {fg,fg56,jk}

Comment: A Linq query for this would be hard to read and inefficient. Better use a good old `foreach` loop with a `HashSet` to keep track of previously added items

Comment: @KooKiz _A Linq query for this would be hard to read and inefficient._ Please clarify.

Comment: On what basis do you include `c34` as-is, but map `a1` to `a`? Please edit this information into your question.

Comment: So `gh465`, `gh1` and `gh` would all map to `gh`. Would `gh465` map to `gh46` also? Or only `gh4651` maps to `gh465`? (Again, please edit this information into your question.)

Comment: @ZevSpitz {gh465,gh1,gh} => {gh,gh,gh}

Comment: And what about pure letter sequences: `{"abcd", "ab"}` => `{"ab", "ab"}` ? (Your question doesn't describe all these details; please edit into the question.)

Comment: @ZevSpitz : {"abcd", "ab"} => {"abcd", "ab"}

Comment: @S.Akbari Because it's a string comparison based on other values. If this value starts with any other value, return that other value; otherwise return it as is.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Hard to read because it's pretty much impossible to guess the intent just by reading the query. Inefficient because it's a solution of o(n²) complexity, where we could reach o(n log n) using a foreach loop with a HashSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are going to be no more than 5 strings at a time, efficiency is not a concern here.

```
var original = new List<string>() {"a","a1","c34","b","b1"};
var mapped = original.Select(x => original.Where(y => x.StartsWith(y)).Min()).ToList();
```

Note also that the comparison is case-sensitive; this can be fixed by passing in the [appropriate StringComparison argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
var res = original.Select(c => c.Replace(c.Length == 2 ? c[1] : ' ', ' ')).ToList();
```

Input:

> { "a", "a1", "c34","a2", "b", "b1" } or  {"a", "a1", "a2", "b", "b1"}

Output:

> { "a", "a", "c34","a", "b", "b" } or {"a", "a", "a", "b", "b"}

Comment: You can use a multi-line lambda statement for clarity, as this question involves LINQ to Objects and `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: I guess this wouldn't work for the input (mentioned in the comments) of {fg,fg56,jk} ?

Comment: @David_001 I think the behavior for `fg56` is like `c34` as OP mentioned in comments because he didn't said `fg56` should be mapped to `fg`!

Comment: Also, will this holds good for {test,test1,nothing} to {{test,test,nothing} as OP mentions it as dynamic

Comment: This is a good code, may need additional conditions like Alphabet check at a given index, based on use cases. Not possible to cover all undefined use cases +1

Comment: @user1400915 I've provided the answer based on the OP's expected output that mentioned in his/her original post and also comments. We can't provide a complete answer until he/she has a common pattern for mapping. For example are you sure `test1` should be `test`? because he/she didn't mentioned it explicitly.