# Error Message for textbox when an alphabet is submitted

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am trying to put an error message for a textbox. The error message will show that only numbers are allowed after pressing a submit button. Are there any codes like that which will not affect the rest of my codes? I tried using the codes below but the error message does not show so an error occured.

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textbox1.Text, @"[^0-9],[^0-9]"))
{
  MessageBox.Show("Only Numbers Allowed.");
  textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Remove(textbox1.Text.Length - 1);
  return;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it affected the other codes."? Also, how is this related to sql?

Comment: Which type of program you use? You can put this kind of code on `KeyPress` handler (if Windows Forms) or `PreviewKeyDown` handler (if WPF).

Comment: Try this to remove digits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657282/how-to-remove-numbers-from-string-using-regex-replace

Answer (score 0):

If you want allow only digits be inputed to TextBox, it's better to use key press/key down handlers to capture what key was pressed and handle it, if key isn't digit:

For **Windows Forms**:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.KeyPress += OnKeyPress;
}

private void OnKeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "[0-9]"))
        e.Handled = true;

    // or shorter

    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

For **WPF**:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.PreviewKeyDown += OnKeyDown;
}

private void OnKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(), "[0-9]"))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Don't forget, that instead of input from keyboard, text may be **pasted** to TextBox, so you may need some `OnPaste` handlers, examples of which you can find:

- for **Windows Forms**: [hook on default "Paste" event of WinForms TextBox control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446233/hook-on-default-paste-event-of-winforms-textbox-control)
- for **WPF**: [Paste Event in a WPF TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061475/paste-event-in-a-wpf-textbox)